# A particular Cauchy problem for first-order PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms, cauchy-problem, jet-bundles

Is the following result true?

*Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $W\subseteq J^1M\cong M\times T^\ast M$ is an open subset, $F\colon W\to \mathbb R$ is a smooth function, and $(x_0,u_0,p_0)\in W$. Let us assume that there is a smooth section $\sigma\in \Gamma(T^\ast M)$ such that $\sigma(x_0)=p_0$. Then there is a function $u$ defined on an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that*
$$
\begin{cases}
F(x,u(x),du(x))=0\\
u(x_0)=u_0\\
du(x_0)=p_0
\end{cases}
$$

This result seems a case of Theorem 22.39 when $S=\{x_0\}$. Am I right?

Thanks for any help.
[image]

Comment: Isn’t $S$ assumed to be a smooth hypersurface in the theorem?

Comment: A point is only an immersed submanifold? @Deane

Comment: A point is a zero dimensional manifold. A hypersurface has dimension one less than the dimension of the manifold. Do you know how to define the dimension of a manifold?

Comment: Ah, you're right... I read "$S$ is an embedded Submanifold."